# Drawing in Qt using QDraw - can't locked the drawing and isn't draw without maximize window

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, drawing

I writing Simulation vehicle from point A to point B with given parameter of blocked road in Qt (using the QPainter) on Xbuntu. I uploaded the code on [Github](https://github.com/pawel112/qt_simulator_vehicle_moving_around_the_city).

1. Without maximize the window and restore the previous size, the board it isn't drawn. How to fix it?
2. Is is possible to locked the drawing? Because the paintEvent method was always executed.
   When I used the setUpdatesEnabled (false), the main window was frozen.

The paintEvent method:

```
    void main_window::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(event);

        try
        {
            if (!((this->new_city->get_size_field1() == -1) && (this->new_city->get_size_field2() == -1)))
            {
                int x = -1;
                int y = -1;
                ui->actionNew_simulation->setDisabled(true);
                this->q = new QPainter (this);
                this->new_city->draw_city(this->q);
                this->set_car_button();
                this->q->end();
            }
        }

        catch (...)
        {
            //locked drawing
            this->end_simulation();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Tried code from github with Qt5.6 and see the grid and small car without maximization. By the way you have a memory leak because main_window::q is never deleted. You even don't need to have this member pointer in fact. Just do `QPainter p(this); new_city->draw_city(&p);`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I removed the QPainter from main windows add in paintEvent method.

Comment: Do not do any calculations in `paintEvent`. Only do drawing. You also don't need to allocate `QPainter` on the heap, nor use exceptions, nor invoke the painter's `end` method.